# NGINX Reverse proxy with HTTPS

Tags: networking, ssl, nginx, https, reverse-proxy

Follow up of a previous [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/568034/letsencrypt-wildcard-certficate-with-nfs-u-18-04/568224#568224) of mine.

### What I want to do?

I want to have my reverse proxy [NGINX] to redirect incoming webtraffic (HTTP and HTTPS) to the correct server based on the sub-domain.

The traffic towards the reverseproxy (RP) from the internet should be with HTTPS while inside my network I don't mind http traffic.

### What is my current situation?

I got my webservices running, as of now only 2, iRedMail and Kanboard.
Both can be reached via http without a problem.
I was able to share my wildcard certificate from my RP with my other servers (I learned later, this isn't necessary).

However, when I try to reach my Servers domain-name via https over Firefox I get `PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR` and via Chrome `ERR:CONNECTION_CLOSED`. In this case it doesn't matter if I try to reach the webserver on the RP itself or the other 2.

Meaning I understood the NGINX with http proxy but failed when it came to certificates and https proxy.

For my configurations please check out the following pastebins, I don't want this post to be to long. All pasts will be **available for 6 Months**, and I will edit this post to add my failed configuration, if there is any.

- [Reverse-Proxy](https://pastebin.com/dqD1JW5i)
- [Kanboard](https://pastebin.com/KurAMdJ9)
- [iRedMail](https://pastebin.com/kb6y2hFf)
- [DNS-Provider](https://pastebin.com/g3ECBLZC)

And finally the output of logs I thought about:

```
 (Reverse-Proxy)> sudo nano /var/log/nginx/error.log
2020/02/21 07:07:46 [error] 9213#9213: *1 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/02/21 07:08:27 [error] 9213#9213: *2 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/02/21 07:11:46 [error] 9320#9320: *1 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/02/21 07:12:03 [error] 9320#9320: *2 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: www.domain.net, request: "GET /favic$
2020/02/21 07:12:07 [error] 9320#9320: *3 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/02/21 07:23:12 [error] 9320#9320: *4 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/02/21 07:23:12 [error] 9320#9320: *5 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/02/21 07:23:17 [error] 9320#9320: *6 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/02/21 07:23:47 [error] 9320#9320: *7 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/02/21 07:24:47 [error] 9320#9320: *8 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/02/21 07:29:47 [error] 9320#9320: *10 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/02/21 07:39:48 [error] 9320#9320: *11 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2020/02/21 07:53:21 [error] 9320#9320: *12 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

I tried this from 7 am to 9 am, but the log stopped with errors around 8 am. I also checked the logs of the Kanboard server, but nothing was reported, neither for access nor error.

### What I have checked so far:

1. If I change the portforward for https directly to my mailserver I can access it without a problem
2. I checked my RP-config for path errors regarding the certificate

### Stacks I went through so far:

[NGINX RP for multiple Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/706694/use-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-multiple-servers),[Redirect via Subdomain](https://serverfault.com/questions/273679/redirecting-to-other-internal-servers-based-on-sub-domain/273694#273694),[NGINX SSL in Home Network](https://superuser.com/questions/1335598/setup-home-network-with-multiple-ssl-devices-on-one-ip/1335800#1335800)

Please tell me if you need anymore information.
PS: All IPs and Domains have been altered by me.
PPS: The pastebins have also been used for my certificate question.

### EDITS:

- Pastebin - Reverseproxy has been tweaked regarding the SSL config. (look for the ## in the pastebin). New error message `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` for access on subdomains. Domain itselfs works partly.
- Pastebin - Reverseproxy has been tweaked again, to a solution I found. Each change has been commented with ## again

Comment: I think that the error message is quite explicit. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) for details.

Comment: @RichardSmith I have to admit, I overlooked the problem in the config (listen 443 ssl:). But this also left me with confussion and another Problem right now. I am now able to access https://example.com but why doesn't the redirect for https (domain.com to www.example.com) work? And new error on https://kanboard.* and mail.* 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'. Thanks for pointing out the log so far, sometimes 4 eyes see more than 2.

Comment: Your redirection error is likely because your redirects don't work the way you expect them to. Also please decide whenever you want to use exmaple.com or domain.net or something else. It's confusing to keep up. Why do you use a reverse proxy on domain.net to access www.domain.net? Your redirection problem might be related to configuration load order.

Comment: @Seth Hello, I tried posting my domain, but Superuser told me to use example.com instead, not sure why, maybe my Rank isn't high enough yet. The reason I redirect: I use a wildcard certificate, meaning *.example.com will be accepted but not example.com. And I had problems with a cname entry on my DNS before, not able to resolve my kanboard. And the redirection order, do you mean I should try to place e.g my mail block at the top of my config?

Comment: Your not using a redirection (301/302) you're using a reverse proxy connection on your own domain. Domain Names [RFC 2606](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606). Request [Understanding Nginx Server and Location Block Selection Algorithms](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms) and [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).

Comment: @Seth thanks for the knowledge input and indirect pointer to a mistake of mine. I also read through the websites you linked. I have to say I didn't see how the related to my problem - since each block listened to a single domain and only had one location to proxy / redirect to. I was able to find a solution nonetheless. Maybe I am just with my head in the clouds and didn't see the pointer you were giving me. I appreciate your help, maybe have a look at the answer I will post shortly. Maybe I made some common mistakes you shouldn't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Richard Smith and Seth giving me things to look at and pointing out flaws, I was able to get my servers running properly.

In the end I had a faulty Reverse-Proxy Configuration - at some settings I must have been blind, but here is what I changed.

Within `>sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/apache` (apache is the name of my config file, yes I know misleading).

I changed quite a lot actually:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen 443 ssl;                                                         ## Listen on 443 ssl
 ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;        ## use this cert
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;      ## and this key
server_name example.com;                                                 ## react to this name-header
return 301 https://www.example.com;                                      ## and redirect everything to www.example.com on https
}
```

Before I forgot to use the paths for the cert and the key and did use a proxy-pass instead of a redirect.

I also added a new Block on my Config, that will simply listen to all traffic on 80 for www.example.com and redirect it to https, so basically the same as above with another `server-name`.

The block of www.example.com that listens to 443 (https) got changed in the `location` aswell.

```
location / {                                                            ## in any scenario
root /var/www/html/;                                                    ## give this directory
}
```

I moved the path down and added the root directive. Because if I understood [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms) correctly, having it at the `location /` would mean it will only listen to URI requests targeting that directory.

And the final change has been the `proxy_pass` for the Kanboard and the iRedMail server.
Before:

```
location / {
 proxy_pass http://10.10.10.26;
 ...
 }
```

After:

```
location / {
 proxy_pass https://10.10.10.26;
 ...
 }
```

I have to admit, I'm not quite sure why I have to pass the traffic with https, but this simply means I didn't understand the Proxy and/or Reverse-proxy completly.

(I expected sending the pass with https would give me the warning regarding mutliple certificates again and also thought that with the "pass" the communication would go on in my Network, meaning http traffic would be sufficent).

PS: @Seth, the following message is the reason I used example.com

> Body cannot contain "My-Fake-Domain".
>   Please use example.com (or .org or .net) for fake URLs. [More Info](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963/why-are-certain-example-urls-like-http-site-com-and-http-mysite-com-blocke)

The whole config, with commented changes will be available at my pastebin for the next 6 months.

And again, if you need anymore information, if I made a mistake (again) or have a flaw in my changes, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The error is often not related to the browser. In our case it was also not a configuration thing of nginx, but a wrong setting of the firewall. So logically, when I say that often has nothing to do with the browser, server-side and not client-side. Accordingly, it was not a proxy or VPN.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.